# Large image not displaying in Excel using Apache POI

Tags: apache-poi

I am trying to paste a 'JPEG' image file to Excel 2013 32-bit version. But after writing the workbook when I am opening it I am getting an error "The image cannot currently be displayed". The image file is very large.

I am using Windows 7 64 bit with Microsoft Excel 32 bit verison.

here is the portion of code to paste the image following the apache POI documentation. -

```
XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
InputStream graphImage = new FileInputStream(fileName);
//Byte array to store the Image in Byte format
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(graphImage);
//Image Id
int imageId = frameWorkbook.addPicture(bytes,Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG);
graphImage.close();

//Instance of ClientAnchor
ClientAnchor anchor = new XSSFClientAnchor();
anchor.setAnchorType(ClientAnchor.DONT_MOVE_AND_RESIZE);
//Setting start position of the Image 
anchor.setCol1(5);
anchor.setRow1(5);
//Instance of XSSFpicture to paint the image
XSSFPicture picOfGraph = drawing.createPicture(anchor,imageId);
picOfGraph.resize();
```

This code works fine with small size image but if the image size gets larger then I am getting the error????Any solution??

Comment: Resize the image to something sensible before you insert it?

Comment: I actually tried to resize the image with the double values 0.5, 1.0, 2.0 but nothing worked.

Comment: I meant resize it with the normal Java Image IO stuff before giving it POI